# How to check if a point on a graph is around a given line (slope intersect form) in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, line

I am trying to write some code in Python to see if a current position that we calculate is within +/- 10 distance to a line. We have the slope intercept form calculated already but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for this specific boundary.

```py
def followLine(currentPosition):
    # y = 1.333x - 666.67
    # if x and y is between +10 and -10 of the formula
    # if (y+10 | y -10) = 1.333(x-10 or x + 10) - 666.67?
```

How can we do this in Python? I am thinking somehow we have code to check if the points are between the lines `y = 1.333x - 656.67` and `y = 1.333x-676.67`. So, points `(560, 73)`, `(640, 190)` would be inside the range that we want, but `(700,100)` would not. A visual representation of this is included below.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU5ai.jpg)

Comment: [Distance from a point to a line](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/) is achieved by doing a dot product, which is available in numpy library as `np.dot()`. Then I'd recommend you take a look ar how conditionals work in python and the logical operators `and` `or` (don't use `|`)

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Just google Python distance point to line: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perpendicular-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-in-2-d/